CY5 and Alexa 488 absorbance
I was trying to measure standard solution of CY5 (at $\pu{649 nm}$; concentrations: $10, 5,$ and $\pu{1 \mu M}$) and Alexa 488 (at $\pu{496 nm}$; concentrations: $20, 10, 5 ,2.5,$ and $\pu{1 \mu M}$) by absorbance (separately), but I couldn't get any difference between any solution just like the background.
But I get results with measure fluorescence. I am not interested in fluorescence because I am afraid of quenching. Any expectation why can't get absorbance?

You need to add some details, what concentrations are you using and what wavelength range for absorption? I would suggest $10^{-4}$ to $10^{-5}$ molar and 800 to 300 nm range as a start.

Dear porphyrin, I added the concentrations information. for the wavelength I used the ones recommended by manufacturer and literatures. (CY5, 649nm; Alexa488, 496nm).

What are your absorbance readings? These solutions should absorb intensely around 490 nm.

You said:

I couldn't get any difference between any solution just like the background.

That means to me is you may not see absorbances increase with increasing concentrations. If that true, it could be due to the wavelength of your detection $(\pu{649 nm})$. It is known Cy5 can be excited by light of $\pu{649 nm}$ wavelength, and it emits red fluorescence light at $\pu{670 nm}$ (Ref. 1). Yet Ref. 1 shows the absorbance spectrum of Cy5 as follows:

I have emphasized the absorbance peak without filters and emission peak with filters for your attention. Since you are looking for just absorbance, I think you should switch to detection at $\pu{630 nm}$. The Ref. 1 also shown their relevant calibration curve as shown below:

It shows the linear relationship between $10^2$ to $\pu{10^5 nm L-1}$ concentration range of Cy5 solutions. I think you may adjust to that range as well.
Alexa 488 behave similarly when looking at its excitation-emission spectrum (from courtesy of Ref. 2):

Thus, if you do detection at $\pu{480 nm}$ may give a decent calibration curve (keep in mind this is just trial and error; you may change wavelength between $470$ and $\pu{495 nm}$ to see which gives the better results). My theory based on to avoid overlapping of the absorbance peak and emission peak.
References:

Kumiko Miyajima, Hiromi Kon, Takahiro Arakawa, Kiyoko Shiba, and Kohji Mitsubayashi, "Fluoroimmunoassay System for Fiber-Optic Measurement of House Dust Mite Allergen (Der f1)," Sensors and Materials 2015, 27(9), 871-880 (ODI: https://doi.org/10.18494/SAM.2015.1182).
W. Adam Shirley, Cynthia Handley, Sabrina Bryant, and Margot Hall, "Quantitation of Immunoglobulin E Using Fluorescence Assay," The Chemist: Journal of the American Institute of Chemists 2014, 87(2), 1-7 (ISSN: 1945-0702).

